# Limiting value of expectation of $\operatorname{tr}(BR(z))$, where $R(z) := (X^\top X - z I_d)^{-1}$ and $X \sim N_{n,d}(0,A)$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, free-probability

Let $A=A(d)$, and $B=B(d)$ be (sequences of) deterministic positive-definite $d \times d$ matrices and let $X$ be an $n \times d$ random matrix with iid rows from $N(0,A)$. Let $R$ be the resolvent of the (recaled) empirical covariance matrix $S := X^\top X$, given by
$$
R(z) := (S-z I_d)^{-1}\text{ for any }z \in \mathbb C^+,
$$
and define $m(z) := \mathbb E[\operatorname{tr}(BR(z))]$.

Assume that $A$ and $B$ have limiting spectral distributions as $d \to \infty$.

**Question.** Let $\phi \in (0,\infty)$ be fixed. In the limit
$$
\label{1}
\tag{1}
n,d \to \infty\text{ such that }d/n \to \phi,
$$
what is the value of $m(z)$ ?

### Notes

- I'm only interested in computations for small $z$, i.e $z \to 0$.
- If it helps, it may also be assumed that $BA^{-1}$ has a limiting spectral density.
- I've looked in Bai and Silverstein's book (Chapter 4) but I don't see anything which applies to my problem.

### Solution for the case $\phi \lt 1$

WLOG, let $n \ge d + 2$. Then, it is a standard result that
$$
\mathbb E R(0) = \mathbb E (X^\top X)^{-1} = \frac{1}{n-d-1}A^{-1}.
$$

We deduce that in the limit \eqref{1},
$$
m(0) = \frac{1}{n-d-1}\operatorname{tr}(B A^{-1}) = \frac{d}{n-d-1}\overline{\operatorname{tr}}(B A^{-1}) \to \frac{\phi}{1-\phi}\cdot\lim_{d \to \infty} \overline{\operatorname{tr}}(BA^{-1}),
$$

where $\overline{\operatorname{tr}} := (1/d)\operatorname{tr}$ is the normalized trace operator.

Comment: Just to clarify: The matrix $B$ is not of special importance, since, by linearity of expectation we have $\mathbb{E}tr(BR(z)) = tr(B\mathbb{E}(R(z)))$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is true by linearity but doesn't provide any particular insight, and I wrote it that way for good reason. Indeed, it's easier to analyze the limiting spectral density of a resolvent than the expectation of the resolvent. This is already clear in the case where $B=A=I$: It's easier to compute the limit of $tr(BE(R(z)))$ than trying to compute $E(R(z))$ and then computing the limit of its trace. The matrix B does play a big role. I hope I didn't miss anything in what you wrote.